# Only when the user lifts his finger should refresh performed

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using [**Refresher**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/) component with `Ionic 3` app.It is working fine.But now I have a requirement where **only when the user lifts his finger should refresh performed, if not, then refresh action is canceled**. Do you know how to implement such functionality?

*.html*

```
 <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="getData($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" pullingText="Pull to refresh" 
     refreshingSpinner="circles" refreshingText="Refreshing...">
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
```

*.ts*

```
getData(refresher?: any) {
  Observable.forkJoin([myTopicApi, myarticlApi, myPicksAPi])
      .subscribe(res => {
        if (refresher) { refresher.complete(); }//terminate refresher
      },
      error => {
        if (refresher) { refresher.complete(); }
      },
      () => { if (refresher) { refresher.complete(); } }
      )
}
```

Comment: Since you are using the built in `Refresher` component, there is no other way you can mess with the component. How about try setting the `pullMax` and `snapbackDuration` to a really large number (or infinity)? Not sure about performance consequences though

Comment: Here's a link to the Referesher component source on Github https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/refresher/refresher.ts It may help someone answer your question